# How to do an Excel FILTER including a match on multiple (arbitrary) fields?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a FILTER considering to include a match on several columns (whose number is not predefined at start). Explaining...

Consider the following table:

| KEY | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | XXXX | YYYY | ZZZZ |
| B | YYYY | XXXX |  |
| C |  | ZZZZ |  |

I want to FILTER when COL1 OR COL2 OR COL3 contain, for instance, "XXXX". The result here would be:

| KEY |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

I know I can do the following, and it works:

- =FILTER(A1:A4;(B1:B4="XXXX")+(C1:C4="XXXX")+(D1:D4="XXXX");"")

The question is that the number of columns COL can grow/shrink and one would need to add many OR conditions on the include which is non practical.

I was expecting to be able to do something like the following:

- =FILTER(A1:A4;B1:D4="XXXX";"")

But this does not work as the FILTER include parameter needs to have size 1 column per 4 rows in order to operate.

I understand that, to do this, I might "just" need to create an array with TRUEs/FALSEs that can then be used in the include of the FILTER function. But my Excel skills do not go so deep :)

Question: how to I do this in one Excel formula ?

Comment: So what would be the expected result for given sample data?

Comment: You could include `BYROW()` to check the count of 'XXXX' per row. Include that in `FILTER()` to avoid having to include any range at all.

Comment: @JvdV Your BYROW() approach is spot on, but we can just simplify the logic and not need COUNT or an IF, to simply a single "OR".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were headed in the right direction.  `B1:D4="XXXX"` gets you to a 3 column by 4 row array of TRUE and FALSE values.  What you're wanting to do is then perform a ***"row-wise OR of all the values in each row, one row at a time."***  So...  Let's *actually do* just that, a row-wise OR of each row:

```
=BYROW(B1:D4="XXXX",LAMBDA(r,OR(r)))
```

This will result in a column array like `{TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}` where TRUE means one or more matches and FALSE means no matches.  In this case, rows 1 and 2 had matches, row 3 and 4 did not.

BYROW steps through each row of a two-dimensional array, and passes the row to a lambda function.  (Note that in the BYROW/BYCOL functions, the LAMBDA is passed the *entire row/column content* as an array.  This is in contrast to a function like MAKEARRAY where the "r" value passed to the LAMBDA is simply the current row number and not the content.)

Then:

```
=FILTER(A1:A4,BYROW(B1:D4="XXXX",LAMBDA(r,OR(r))))
```

Now you can just edit A4 and D4 to be what you need and you're off and running.

If this filter is going to become part of a more complicated formula, consider:

```
=LET(
matchingRows, BYROW(B1:D4="XXXX",LAMBDA(r,OR(r))),
matchingValues, FILTER( A1:A4, matchingRows ),
// then use "matchingValues" in another formula //
)
```

Comment: Tried it and it works just top ! Indeed, I understood what I needed to do just not how to get there. Indeed I did not even knew that Excel has the lambda function :) Many thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to filter out the values if any of the columns contain value "XXXX" in the same row.
In that case you could use:

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,MMULT(--(B2:D4="XXXX"),SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:D4),,1,0)))
```

Or using `BYROW`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,BYROW(B2:D4,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(x,"XXXX"))))
```

Or more dynamically;

```
=LET(range,A2:D4,
     key,INDEX(range,,1), 
     cols,INDEX(range,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),SEQUENCE(1,3,2)),
FILTER(key,MMULT(--(cols="XXXX"),SEQUENCE(ROWS(cols),,1,0))))
```

Comment: Tried the COUNTIF , it works but the worksheet starts to run slow - because I have some 10 computations of this, I presume the COUNTIF takes time. Tried the lambda/OR solution suggested after and it works just great - many thanks.

Comment: @Pedro  That's puzzling, P.b's approach isn't something that should "feel" different even if you were doing hundreds of iterations.

Comment: You're helped, that's what counts. I can't think of a reason why the COUNTIF version would slow it down.

Comment: It is strange, but it happens yes. When I have the COUNTIF takes some 2~3 seconds to get responsiveness back from Excel. With OR it is mostly immediate. Anyway, it works and that is what I wanted to know. I might try the LET later so see. Thanks.